# Transitive maven dependencies with Intellij IDEA 12: Can't compile + Breakpoints do not stop

Tags: java, maven, debugging, intellij-idea

I am having 4 poms: 1 parent and 3 sub poms. It looks like this:

parent
-- core
-- wcs
-- web

We are having that setup since a long time. I am facing now issues, my colleague does not have the problems despite using a similar environment.
I worked on these poms, modified them. "Out of a sudden" classes in the web module which have import statements which reference dependencies of the core module are causing compilation problems (cannot find symbol). By moving the core module dependencies into the parent module I was able to fix the issue (which was not an issue before).

When I start maven jetty plugin in web module not all breakpoints are working. The breakpoints in web module are all working, however the breakpoints in core module are not working. I also tried the debug command "Step into" to force Intellij to open at least a compiled class file but without any succes. Even stranger was that breakpoints of one package in the core module were working properly but breakpoints in other packages were not working.

I shared my pom changes with my colleague and he does not have such issues as I do. For some time it was also working for me. Then I changed the profiles section in web modules pom and had all the issues again. Right away I reverted my pom changes but the issues stayed.

I tried invalidate caches without any success.

My next step would be uninstalling Intellij and installing Intellij 14. After that only re-installing my whole system is the last option.

However I would like to understand what I can do else? Is there any way that I can tell Intellij to "activate" the mapping again? Is there maybe additionally something cached by Intellij?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the related parts of my local maven repository and the issues were eventually gone.